# Request permission from antivirus or operating system to execute

Tags: c#, .net, antivirus

I wrote a program in c# .net 4.5 that doesn't execute unless I turn off my anti-virus (avast) or add the path of it into the anti-virus whitelist.

Is there any way to ask permissions in code to let the anti-virus loose off my program?

Comment: What is your program *doing* that's causing the antivirus to block it? That's going to be the real answer to your problem.

Comment: Actually I got 2 programs, a server and a client. I think the anti-virus is blocking them because i use sockets on a random port without any permission.

Comment: If this would be possible to achieve it kind of defeats the whole point of anti-virus programs, doesn't it?

Comment: Can you run the programs elevated and see if that still gives you a false positive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No . It is not possible and all the modern anti virus doesn't have such an api.
The only thing you can do is send your file to anti-virus provider site to analyse if they accept and didn't detect any malicious effort then they will send the clients a white-list signature (of your file).

Here is some example for you to send your file for analyse :

1 . Avg
[Avg White-list service](http://www.avg.com/submit-sample)

2 . Read how to do it on Avast [Avast white-list](https://www.avast.com/en-us/faq.php?article=AVKB229)

3 . Kaspersky [white-list](http://whitelist.kaspersky.com/advisor)

4 . Eset Nod32 [White-list](http://support.eset.com/kb3345/?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)

and etc . that you can googling about it.

Hope it helps